# How to config connection to mongo database on MongoLab using java mongodb driver, java configuration (not xml configuration)?

Tags: java, mongodb, web-applications, database-connection, mlab

Currently I'm using Amzone EC2 to host my mongo database, below is code for MongoCongig file in java using java mongodb driver and it's working fine.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration
{

    @Value("my_amazone_ec2_host")
    private String host;

    @Value("27017")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("my_database_name")
    private String database;

    @Value("database_admin")
    private String username;

    @Value("admin_pass")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName()
    {
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception
    {
        return new MongoClient(
                singletonList( new ServerAddress( host, port ) ),
                singletonList( MongoCredential.createCredential( username,
                        database, password.toCharArray() ) ) );
    }
}
```

Now I want to using MongoLab to host my database and MongoLab provide URI to connect to mongo db something like this:

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ser_num.mongolab.com:port/database_name
```

I tried to modify my host name with this URI but not successful. Can anyone help me config this file?
I'm using only java configuration, not XML configuration; MongoDB version 3.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution by replacing relative information from MongoLab URI:

```
@Value("ser_num.mongolab.com")
private String host;

@Value("port")
private Integer port;
```